# How to avoid crashing with ConformImages?

Tags: bugs, image-processing, crash, machine-learning

`ConformImages[]` is causing a kernel crash when applied to a list of 5k images. Is there any way to apply ConformImages on the list in batches or asynchronously to conserve memory?

Here's the behavior:

[image]

**Update:**

Actually the function itself seems buggy, since it crashes on only 2 images:

[image]

There must be some weird property of the images that I'm using that causes the function to crash. I've posted them to imgur: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qIHB.jpg

- Seems like the exif data in these images might be causing ConformImages to crash the kernel.

Comment: The root cause of this crash is the ColorConvert function.  For images with ColorProfileData (as is the case for the image on the left), ColorConvert crashes the kernel.  This bug was present in versions 10.2 and 10.3.  It has been fixed in 10.3.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to avoid crashing in 10.3 and below. So the answer is upgrade to the newest version 10.3.1. @ChadK was right, there is no crash now after updating:

[image]

Comment: The answer is "upgrade to 10.3.1". What more information should I add?